# Get similar rows in data frame that only changes 1 value or more per column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My problem is the following: imagine you have a dataframe NxM filled with binary numbers:

```
pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I would like to get the index or rows (iterating by row) of two similar rows that only changes **by 1 value per column or more**. For instance, the similarity for the first rows would be:

- if they only changes by one value per column:

row 0: `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]` -> expected output `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`
row 2: `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` -> expected output `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

- if they changes by two values per column:

row 2: `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` -> expected output `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`
row 4: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]` -> expected output `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`

Comment: An observation.  If your rows were represented by numbers instead of split into binary, you could generate all numbers that are one bit away by xor with each of `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128` (assuming you had 8 bits).  Conversely any number that you xor with the original number would be one bit away if the result is in the set `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128`. For two bits it gets more complicated. Your list of numbers would be `set(map(sum, itertools.combinations([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128], r=2)))`. (length of 28 for 8 bits - and for 32 bits that becomes 496 numbers that are 2 bits away).

Comment: For example `5 ^ 7` is `2` which is in the set `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128` so it's one bit away, but `5 ^ 9` is `12` which is not in the set, so it's not one bit away.  Also `5 ^ 2` gives back your original `7`.  And `5 ^ 128` gives `133` which is also one bit away.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the records.  After shifting you can compare values to return True/False.  After this you count the True Values.  I set true==1 for the example so you have exactly 1 change between lines.

I'm unsure exactly what your specific outcome is supposed to look like but maybe you can enhance this.

```
print(df)

print(df.shift(-1))

df[df[df == df.shift(-1)].isna().sum(axis=1) == 1]
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  0  1  0  1
1  0  1  0  1  0  1
2  1  0  0  0  0  0
3  1  1  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  1  0
5  1  1  0  0  1  0

     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
4  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

Out[54]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  0  1  0  1
2  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the hamming distance to have the pairwise distance between rows:

```
import sklearn.metrics
comparisons = sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances(df.values,metric='hamming')
nb_of_differences = (comparisons * df.shape[1]).astype(int)
```

The hamming distance counts the number of positions where 2 vectors differ. In the end, you get a matrix giving you the number of differences between row i and row j.